# Flagging users of another role to not see me in a user listing

Tags: views, flags

I am looking for a way to achieve this:

Everything happens with logged in users

User with Role A can flag users of Role B

User with Role B can see a views list of users with Role A EXCLUDING the users of Role A that have flagged the user of Role B currently watching the list of all Role A users.

The use case:
Users of Role A are open for job offers. But Role B (companies) should not see their own employees looking for a new job. So Role A user can hide himself from his current employer with the flagging.

Played around with a ton of various contextual filter variantions, but none seems to do the trick. Also you always get duplicate entries as soon as the Flag User Relationship is added.

Comment: Is this the same as these unanswered prior questions? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/316913/user-flag-is-not-parsed https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317088/show-user-fields-on-user-page-if-user-has-flagged-the-viewer

Comment: no. it is somewhat similar, but different. same church, different pew. the other one has been solved meanwhile